# Hide link button text and show image instead

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asplinkbutton

if you dont understand what i said please do let me know via comments
donot flag or downvotes

I am having linkbutton , that is used top getting Id in GridView.

I want to show Image instead of text..
I am attaching Image . See on the left side top marked section
I want to get rid of text **7241**

Below is my code.. but I m in need of getting 7241 on the jquery click,,, see at bottom the jquery code

**ASP.Net Code**

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSubmission" CssClass="PopupShow" runat="server"
                                                                        data-toggle="modal" ToolTip="Make Submission"  data-target="#Submission"><%# Eval("fk_LoginId") %>
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-location-arrow" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                                    </asp:LinkButton>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
 $(function () {
            $('.PopupShow').click(function () {
                var a = $(this).text();
                $("#<%=CID.ClientID%>").val(a);
            });
        });
```

**Current Image is**

[image]

Comment: Why not an image link like `<a><img src="#" /></a>`

Comment: Are you using it in GridView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and below code is working:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnRandom"  runat="server"  CssClass="btn btn-primary PopupShow" >
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"> <label id="lbl" style="display:none;"><%#Eval("fk_LoginId")%></label> </span>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.PopupShow').click(function () {                    
          var a = $(this).find('label').html();
          console.log(a);
          alert(a);
          return false;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

why are you using linkbutton then??

```
<img src="path to your image"  class="PopupShow"/>
```

you can even call this using `onClick=`

make sure `PopupShow` class wont disfigure your image style or just add any random blank class with `cursor:pointer`

Comment: You have to be more clear about your answer. Now it has no value to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customizing a LinkButton you can use an image Embedded `<a>` tag. With its `href` points to the redirection URL of the Link button. And also you can bind specific image URL to the img tag as well. Consider an example code below

```
<a href="<%#Eval("url_here")%>" Class="PopupShow">
      <img src="i<%#Eval("img_url_here")%>" />
</a>
```

Or else you can use a javascript to do the function and call the method in `onClick` of the img tag